# Why use of "override" is not allowed in method definition?

Tags: c++, c++11

Override is quite informative keyword. However, one can use it in class declaration only. Is there any reason to forbid its use in definitions? Example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Method() = 0;
};

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    void Method() override;
};


// source.cpp

void Child::Method() override        // oops
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sometimes I wish it could stay there because I often implement methods by copying them from the class declaration into my source file, but then I forget to remove the `override`

Comment: What would be the benefit of able to use it in the definition? All it can do is cause confusion (e.g. what does it mean if the definition says "override" and the declaration doesn't?)

Comment: They went with the whole "identifier with a special meaning" rather than a keyword, so I guess they were being extra restrictive. Speculation only though...

Comment: @juanchopanza, all we have now is "the declaration says "override" and the definition doesn't". That'd be good if it was at both places, like "const", wouldn't it?

Comment: On the one hand, I agree with you. On the other hand, the same is true of the "virtual" keyword, correct? So we're several decades late objecting to the rule. Additionally, virtual and override are not part of the prototype, so they can't really mean anything outside of the class declaration.

Comment: @KennyOstrom, yeah, they aren't cv-qualifier, i.e. not part of a common function prototype. But I guess it's time to introduce new rules about class method qualifiers, because there's also a keyword "final", and it makes 3 keywords to be omitted in the method definition. That ain't good.

Comment: Not to mention the =0 and any default values...
The list is ever growing.
I'm sure that in the past compilers allowed these decorations in the definition as long as they exactly matched the declaration, but those times are long gone.